# Какая логика расчета размера экрана смартфона

Tags: design, экран

На англоязычном [сайте](https://worship.agency/mobile-screen-sizes-for-2023-based-on-data-from-2022) нашел список размеров экранов смартфонов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему в этом списке например `IPhone 12` с разрешением `1170 x 2532` имеет размер `390 х 844`, как они это высчитали и почему просто не указали его фактическое разрешение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы страничка вебсайта была читаема на смартфоне, придумали адаптивную настройку видимой области (`Viewport`). К примеру `IPhone 12` имеет разрешение `1170 x 2532` и плотность пикселей на дюйм `460 ppi`, если в таком разрешении будет отображаться вебсайт то шрифт на экране смартфона будет попросту не видно из-за маленького значения в пикселях относительно экрана смартфона. Из-за этого разрешение экрана смартфона искусственно уменьшается, и вебсайт отображается так, как если бы он отображался на смартфоне с более низким разрешением экрана.

Формула для расчета того насколько сильно уменьшится дисплей следующая:
Если экран имеет плотность меньше `200 ppi`, то разрешение будет равно физическому. Если экран имеет плотность пикселей от `200 ppi` до `300 ppi`, то новое разрешение будет в `1.5` раза меньше физического. А если экран имеет плотность более `300 ppi`, то новое разрешение будет определяться делением физического разрешения на некоторый `коэффициент`. Данный `коэффициент` определяется по формуле - `Плотность / 150 ppi` с округлением обычно до 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4 и т.д.

Например:
`IPhone 12` - реальное разрешение `1170 x 2532 px`, плотность пикселей `460 ppi`. Видим что плотность пикселей на дюйм `IPhone 12` (`460 ppi`) больше чем `300 ppi`, значит коэффициент считаем вручную: `460 ppi / 150 ppi = 3 (3.07 округляем до 3)`. Теперь с помощью данного коэффициента высчитываем искусственное разрешение `IPhone 12` или иначе говоря разрешение нашего `Viewport`: `1170 px / 3 = 390 px`, `2532 / 3 = 844 px`. Теперь фактически имея разрешение `1170 x 2532 px`, страничка вебсайта будет отображаться так, как будто разрешение нашего смартфона `390 х 844 px`.

Следующая картинка демонстрирует тоже самое, только для `IPhone 4`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Информация и материал взяты с сайта - https://itchief.ru/html-and-css/viewport-meta-tag

Answer (score 0):

Apple iPhone 12 имеет физический размер экрана 6,1 дюйма, его разрешение составляет около 1170 x 2532 пикселей с плотностью пикселей примерно 460 PPI . Размер области просмотра Apple iPhone 12 составляет 390 x 844 пикселей, а соотношение пикселей составляет около 3.

viewport - область просмотра.

По простому - если мы открываем сайт в браузере, он не будет имет вид на 1170 x 2532 пикселей.

Дисплей iPhone 12 представляет собой прямоугольник с закруглёнными углами. Диагональ этого прямоугольника без учёта закруглений составляет 6,06 дюйма (фактическая область просмотра меньше).

[Iphone 12 - Спецификация](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP830?locale=ru_RU#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%20iPhone%2012%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9,(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5).)